# Adding values to multidimensional array PHP without overwritting last added value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm having trouble with adding values to an associative multidimensional array and echoing them out. The last value added is the one being echoed out. I tried playing with `$j` next to `$dreams[$name]` but then it only echoes out the first letter. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
echo "How many people should I ask their dreams?" . PHP_EOL;
$many = readline();
$dreams = [];

if (is_numeric($many)) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $many; $i++) {
        echo "What is your name?" . PHP_EOL;
        $name = readline();
        echo "How many dreams are you going to enter?" . PHP_EOL;
        $numberDreams = readline();
        if (is_numeric($numberDreams)) {
            for ($j = 1; $j <= $numberDreams; $j++) { 
                echo "What is your dream?" . PHP_EOL;
                $dreams[$name] = readline();
            }
        }
    }
    echo "In jouw bucketlist staat: " . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($dreams as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . "'s dream is: " . $value . PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    exit($many . ' is not a number, try again.');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
$dreams[$name][] = readLine();
```

This creates a new array entry within `$dreams[$name]` for each entered value. Otherwise yes you're overwriting `$dreams[$name]` every time with a different value.

And then to output, you'll need two loops, one for the names and one for the dreams - it should be a mirror of the input process - because effectively you're doing the process in reverse, with the same data structure:

```
foreach ($dreams as $name => $entries) {
    echo $name . "'s dreams are: ". PHP_EOL;
    
    foreach ($entries as $dream)
    {
      echo $dream.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function and you can replace this line `$dreams[$name] = readline();` with `array_push($dreams[$name], readline());`

Comment: This only solves half the puzzle. See my answer